# Replacing items in a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to map a list and replace the values with items from a dictionary.
1.0 in the list would = 12, etc.

```
list_1 = list([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]])
dict = {1:12, 2:10, 3:5, 4:2, 5:1}
```

Desired output would be:

```
[[12, 10, 5, 12], [5, 12, 10, 2]]
```

Comment: Beside the point, but `list()` does nothing here. It's already a list.

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you want to ask how to do it, what have you already tried? This should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lists = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]]
dic = {1:12, 2:10, 3:5, 4:2, 5:1}

result = [[dic.get(i) for i in x] for x in lists]
```